# Escaping this javascript code in php

Tags: javascript, php, string, escaping

I'm failing at escaping this code snippet that I only want to make visible on the page if a username is logged in. Then it just echoes that code, but as you can see, it's a large chunk that I need to escape. How do I go about that with this? Normally I don't have too much trouble with it myself but this code won't simply work otherwise.

```
//if user is logged in echo the code

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){

echo '
    <noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-PZWSZ2"
   height="0" width="0"   style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
   <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
   new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
   j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
   '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
   })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-PZWSZ2');</script>
   ';
  }
?>
```

Comment: Google PHP nowdoc

Comment: There's no PHP in the HTML part so just break out of PHP ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have single quotes to encapsulate the HTML and more inside the HTML that haven't been escaped `\'`.  See [PHP Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

But to present an alternative since there is no PHP in the HTML, just break out of PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
?>
   <noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-PZWSZ2"
   height="0" width="0"   style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
   <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
   new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
   j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
   '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
   })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-PZWSZ2');</script>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Also see [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) that may be easier or more readable.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach, IMHO would be to use a [nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc):

```
$javascript = <<<'JAVASCRIPT'
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-PZWSZ2"
   height="0" width="0"   style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
   <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
   new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
   j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
   '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
   })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-PZWSZ2');</script>
JAVASCRIPT

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo $javascript;
}
```

Comment: Simplest would be not to use PHP ;-)

Comment: @AbraCadaver even better :-)